# Siri cutting me off while dictating

Tags: ios, siri

As a disabled person who often relies on 'Hey Siri' to transcribe outgoing texts I am finding it increasingly frustrating when I am cut off. This basically happens if there is any silence between sentences. For example:

'Hey Siri' text Mum:
"what do you want to say" (starts transcribing),,,
"I'll be 10 minutes late for dinner. `I was hoping to...`

The part in code there is the part that gets cut off. Being cut of like this happens consistently when trying to get Siri to transcribe anything with more than one sentence or any brief pause in speech.

Using voice transcription in a text field however does not produce this behavior as the prompt for transcription stays until the button is pressed again.

Is there any feature in 'Accessibility' that might fix this bug? It's really annoying.

Using iOS 15.7.5 on Iphone7

Comment: Try changing the *Siri Pause Time* under Accessibility → Siri.  Not sure if that will work, but give it a shot

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't see anything in the Siri section of Accessibility that offers any options about 'pause time'. Are you using  iOS 15.7.5 ?

Comment: It's an iOS 16 new feature. Unfortunately your iPhone 7 is not supported. https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2022/05/apple-previews-innovative-accessibility-features/

Comment: @AndyGriffiths Thanks. Too bad, not buying a new phone anytime soon.

Comment: @Thinkr I mentioned a disability. Try to use your imagination.